# Diferenças entre If e operador ternário ?:

Tags: c#, if, operadores, resharper

Existe diferença de performance entre utilizar um if e um operador ternário em C#?

Utilizo **Resharper** *(Ferramenta de produtividade para o VS)*, ele insiste que o ***operador ternário*** é melhor mas não me explica o porque.

Código, antes do Refactoring:

```
if (int.Parse(dr.ItemArray[16].ToString()) == 1)
{
   txt.Append(@"VENDE-SE");
}
else
{
  txt.Append(@"ALUGA-SE");
}
```

Depois:

```
txt.Append(int.Parse(dr.ItemArray[16].ToString()) == 1
        ? @"VENDE-SE"
        : @"ALUGA-SE");
```

Comment: A diferença é na legibilidade... não que um seja mais que o outro, mas sim que, em certas situações, um é mais legível que o outro.

Comment: Pelo que sei o ReSharper analisa a "simplicidade" do if e sugere a respectiva expressão "?:" para substituir o if. Acredito que tenha ganho em perfomance sim, mas nada tão significativo.
Mas considere uma coisa, analise a leitura completa de seu código e veja se isso é legível para outros programadores. O uso exacerbado dessa expressão pode causar confusão na leitura do código, prejudicando uma futura leitura para manutenções na aplicação.

Comment: concordo, nem sempre o ?: ajuda a legibilidade, no exemplo acima acho que começa o limite de que não compensa o uso dele. normalmente uso para algo simples como return (id == null ? 0 : id);

Comment: Nesse caso, para diminuir código poderia apenas remover as chaves

Comment: @Dorathoto você devia ter deixado a recompensa 1 semana pra dar destaque pra sua pergunta.

Comment: Mas sua resposta já está 100% boa...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

O código

```
public class Exemplo {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var x = 0;
        if (x == 1) {
            x = 1;
        } else {
            x = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

é compilado para

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void Main (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 22 (0x16)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32,
        [1] bool
    )

    IL_0000: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.0             // Push 0 onto the stack as int32
    IL_0002: stloc.0              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0
    IL_0003: ldloc.0              // Load local variable 0 onto stack
    IL_0004: ldc.i4.1             // Push 1 onto the stack as int32
    IL_0005: ceq                  // Push 1 (of type int32) if value1 equals value2, else push 0
    IL_0007: stloc.1              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 1
    IL_0008: ldloc.1              // Load local variable 1 onto stack
    IL_0009: brfalse.s IL_0011    // Branch to target if value is zero (false), short form
    IL_000b: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
    IL_000c: ldc.i4.1             // Push 1 onto the stack as int32
    IL_000d: stloc.0              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0
    IL_000e: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
    IL_000f: br.s IL_0015         // Branch to target, short form
    IL_0011: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
    IL_0012: ldc.i4.2             // Push 2 onto the stack as int32
    IL_0013: stloc.0              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0
    IL_0014: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
    IL_0015: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
} // end of method Exemplo::Main
```

[Pode ser observado no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#f:%3Eil/A4VwRgNglgxgBDCBDAziuBRAHgUwLbAQD2cA3gLABQcNcokscKALks4wG5FQAmcAskigA7ABQsATiIDmAbQC6cJBOkoAlGSq1tcDsrhY4AXjgAGANxadNKADM4ow0ZMBGDRWrWdTuC8ufrAF84HAgUHE0ArxofACZ/aMCrGiTKVKoAegyAC2ZmYAAuLOBmADoWJBgAayIOHAlbYgB3UpgiPAyARwyXAHYAZgBOAA4e0xcgA=).

E o código

```
public class Exemplo {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var x = 0;
        x = (x == 1 ? 1 : 2);
    }
}
```

é compilado para

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void Main (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32
    )

    IL_0000: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.0             // Push 0 onto the stack as int32
    IL_0002: stloc.0              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0
    IL_0003: ldloc.0              // Load local variable 0 onto stack
    IL_0004: ldc.i4.1             // Push 1 onto the stack as int32
    IL_0005: beq.s IL_000a        // Branch to target if equal, short form
    IL_0007: ldc.i4.2             // Push 2 onto the stack as int32
    IL_0008: br.s IL_000b         // Branch to target, short form
    IL_000a: ldc.i4.1             // Push 1 onto the stack as int32
    IL_000b: stloc.0              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0
    IL_000c: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
} // end of method Exemplo::Main
```

[Pode ser observado no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#f:%3Eil/A4VwRgNglgxgBDCBDAziuBRAHgUwLbAQD2cA3gLABQcNcokscKALks4wG5FQAmcAskigA7ABQsATiIDmAbQC6cJBOkoAlGSq1tcDsrhY4AXjgAGANxadNQydG2TARjgB+OM4BccAExrL1WgBfKmDKKgB6cIALZmZgD0jgZgA6FiQYAGsiDhwJADNiAHdkmCI8cIBHcMcAdgBmAE4ADmrTRyA).

Portanto **há diferença**. A diferença é apenas sintática mesmo. Mas em [versão anterior desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/17408/1) não havia diferença. Então é detalhe de implementação, pode mudar de uma versão para outra.

**Ao contrário da crença popular, a versão usando o operador condicional pode ser mais eficiente**.

Mas não é tão simples. Isto pode não ser válido em outras situações. Eu fiz um exemplo simples. A única forma de saber o que realmente vai acontecer e se vai ter a mesma performance, é medindo. É verificando se gera o mesmo código na sua exata situação real na versão do compilador que for usado.

E tem mais, o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) pode fazer mais otimizações e inverter a situação ou deixar nas mesmas condições.

Veja um outro [exemplo de comparação em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17328641/221800).

Você pode fazer a verificação do código IL bruto com o [ildasm.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que vem com o Visual Studio, ou pode usar outro descompilador como o [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), o [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), o [.NET Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) ou o [JustDecompile](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx).

Você deve escolher o que é **melhor para dar entendimento para o que você deseja**. Se precisar usar um operador condicional em uma expressão complexa pode ficar ilegível. Por outro lado criar várias linhas em um `if` para fazer uma simples operação também pode ser um exagero. Uma dica para melhorar a legibilidade do operador condicional e deixar claro que você está montando uma expressão é colocar parênteses em torno da expressão completa (os três operandos como uma coisa só). Claro que há situações que nem isto ajuda.

Se há efeito colateral (alteração de estado), isto precisa ficar claro no código. Me parece que nos casos que apresentei isto fica claro. Mas há casos que o código pode dificultar a leitura do efeito colateral. Você deve evitar esconder possíveis equívocos no código. O operador ternário é mais propenso a isto. Mas também não devemos fugir dele a todo custo. Deve ser observado a pertinência no caso específico.

Exemplo bom:

```
int resultado = Check() ? 1 : 0;
```

Exemplo ruim:

```
int resultado = Check1() ? 1 : Check2() ? 1 : Check3() ? 1 : 0;
```

Apesar que este exemplo pode ser melhorado:

```
int resultado = Check1() ? 1 :
                Check2() ? 1 :
                Check3() ? 1 :
                           0;
```

Uma das vantagens de usar o operador condicional no lugar do `if` é a redução de código duplicado. É bom para manter a **concisão**. Mas isto não pode vir em detrimento da legibilidade do código. **Mais performance para um lado ou para o outro não é vantagem**. O ganho certamente será pequeno mesmo nas situações mais extraordinárias. Se você realmente precisa desse **possível** pequeno ganho de performance, C# não é a linguagem adequada.

O [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) é uma ótima ferramenta (quase obrigatória) e dá ótimas sugestões, mas ele não codifica para você. O programador sempre é necessário para dar contexto ao código. O Resharper não é mais inteligente que você e não sabe se o seu código realmente ficará melhor do jeito que ele sugere. **Ele dá a dica, você decide**.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/ConditionalXIf).

Comment: perfeita resposta, agradeço, sobre o Resharper eu sei que ele não programa, mas como ele insistia dizendo que o operador ternário era melhor achei que seria mais performático, mas seu código da compilação deixa claro que no final é idêntico.

Comment: Claro, apenas para deixar claro para todo mundo, não respondi só para você.

Comment: @AugustoVasques tem algumas, eu até já criei uma palestra, mas o o pessoal iniciante não quer saber de nada, e os mais experientes ou já sabem essas coisas, ou eles são pseudo experientes, ou seja, são iniciantes com tempo de trabalho, e também não ligam pra isso. È como está o mercado, dá desgosto.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que sei o ReSharper analisa a "simplicidade" do if e sugere a respectiva expressão "?:" para substituir o if. Acredito que tenha ganho em perfomance sim, mas nada tão significativo.

Mas considere uma coisa, analise a leitura completa de seu código e veja se isso é legível para outros programadores. O uso exacerbado dessa expressão pode causar confusão na leitura do código, prejudicando uma futura leitura para manutenções na aplicação.