# Como preencher TextBoxes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Não gostaria de usar vários `if's` para controlar um método meu, a menos se não há como fazê-lo sem os `if's`. Gravo em uma lista, o retorno do BD que pode ter ou não informações bancárias. A lista me retorna, `Nome_Banco`, `Conta` e `Agencia`. Preciso preencher uns `textbox`, mas apenas se houver dados. Estou tendo dificuldades para fazer sem o uso de `if's`. Veja como está atualmente.

```
if (vlstCorpFornecedor.Count > 0)
        {
            //string nm_banco = vlstCorpFornecedor[0].Banco.ToString();
            txtCpfCnpjCadFornecedor.Text = vlstCorpFornecedor[0].NuCPFCNPJ.ToString();
            txtNomeRazaoSocialCadFornecedor.Text = vlstCorpFornecedor[0].Nome.ToString();
            txtAgenciaCadFornecedor.Text = vlstCorpFornecedor[0].Agencia.ToString();
            txtContaCadFornecedor.Text = vlstCorpFornecedor[0].ContaCorrente.ToString();
            cmbBancos.SelectedValue = vlstCorpFornecedor[0].Banco.ToString();
            cmbBancos_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

Onde `vlstCorpFornecedor` é a minha lista.  A partir daqui `txtAgenciaCadFornecedor` e só posso preencher se existe ou não dados. Posso fazer com `if's` e testar se é `null` ou não, mas a pergunta é: Existe uma forma de fazer isso sem o `if`?

---

Respondendo ao Maniero.

Esses campos são exibidos em um painel, tipo um "popup". Esses campos estão nesse painel. Quando no formulário eu digito o CPF ou CNPJ, aí o painel é visível e esses campos são preenchidos após a pesquisa no BD. A lista trás: CPF/CNPJ, Razão Social, Agencia, Conta, Número do Banco e Nome do Banco(Instituição).

Bem, acontece, que como se trata de uma cadastro antigo, nem sempre eu tenho as informações bancárias. Então quando o painel é exibido (Visível), se qualquer dados bancário vir `null`, vai dar erro no momento de atribuir valor aos `TextBoxes` relativos.

Gostaria de evitar esse erro já testando `null` nas informações. caso venha nulo, o painel é exibido (Visível) com CPF/CNPJ e Razão Social preenchidos e os demais `textboxes` deverão vir em branco (vazios) para poder ser preenchidos manualmente(usuário digita os campos, agencia, conta, número e nome do banco (instituição)).

Comment: E o que você quer fazer se for `null`?

Comment: Não vai preencher de forma automática. Aí o preenchimento será manual, torno o painel visível com os campos em branco e depois o usuário preenche-os manualmente.

Comment: Mas você tem que explicar como você quer proceder com isto. Suas perguntas são complicadas porque a gente tem que adivinhar como você está fazendo. Que é preenchimento manual? O que é painel visível? Você não fala nada disso na pergunta. Quais campos devem estar em branco? O que é estar em branco para você? Pergunto isto porque você costuma dizer uma coisa mas quer outra. Está havendo algum problema quando faz da forma que você postou?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e tentar ser mais explícito, mas acho que a pergunta está adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem dá para evitar o `if` propriamente dito mas não dá para evitar uma decisão , por isto vou usar um [operador ternário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17398/101) (vou colocar só o que interessa, depois você replica para os outros campos):

```
txtAgenciaCadFornecedor.Text = vlstCorpFornecedor[0].Agencia == null ? 
                                   "" : 
                                   vlstCorpFornecedor[0].Agencia.ToString();
```

Então se o dado for `null` ele pega uma *string* vazia, caso contrário pega o dado.

Você tem certeza que precisa do `ToString()`? Se não precisar dá para simplificar isto usando o operador de [*null-coalescing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44133/101). Não parece precisar.

```
txtAgenciaCadFornecedor.Text = vlstCorpFornecedor[0].Agencia ?? "";
```

Uma alternativa seria criar um método auxiliar. Pensando rápido poderia ser um método de extensão genérico que transformasse em *string* qualquer coisa que recebesse (dá p/ fazer até melhor que isto), algo assim:

```
public static string Coalesce<T>(this T obj, string defaultValue = "") {
    if (obj == null) return defaultValue;
    return obj.ToString();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/CoalesceMethod.cs).

Uso:

```
txtAgenciaCadFornecedor.Text = vlstCorpFornecedor[0].Agencia.Coalesce();
```

Comment: Testei apenas esse e deu certo. txtAgenciaCadFornecedor.Text = vlstCorpFornecedor[0].Agencia ?? "";