# Há algum ganho de performance ao se utilizar operador ternário invés de um operador condicional?

Tags: php, desempenho, operadores

Qual a diferença de performance utilizando **operadores condicionais** e **operadores ternários**? Há algum ganho significativo ou a escolha do uso dos operadores ternários é exclusiva para simplificação de código?

**Exemplo de código com operador condicional:**

```
var x;

if ($foo) {
    x = "John Doe";
} else {
    x = "Foo";
}
```

**Exemplo de código com operador ternário:**

```
var x = $foo ? "John Doe" : "Foo";
```

Comment: Há algo que eu possa melhorar na resposta, ou nas outras?

Comment: Olá @qmechanik, todas as respostas são muito esclarecedoras e detalhadas, deixei um tempo sem marcar alguma pra garantir que não havia mais ninguém a acrescentar algo ou pra não "escolher rápido demais" conforme andei vendo no `meta`.

Comment: Você está fazendo algum estudo ou está realizando ajustes de performance em algum aplicativo web real?

Comment: Olá @Intruso, estou finalizando o desenvolvimento do meu TCC este ano, não possuía o hábito de usar operadores ternários e agora que estou começando me surgiu a dúvida de saber se o meu ganho era apenas em legibilidade ou em algo mais.

Comment: Esse tipo de otimização, geralmente não é feito na maioria das aplicações porque na web, o custo em outros lugares é realmente mais significativo. Você pode dar uma olhada no material desse cara pra entender melhor do que estou falando: https://www.stevesouders.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Importância da performance

PHP é uma linguagem onde a performance não é importante, ela é lenta em grande parte de suas operações. Então tenha em mente que todas informações aqui só são relevantes como curiosidade. O custo do processamento de um ou outro é muito baixo para tudo o que se pretende fazer com PHP. Se precisar de mais performance ainda, outra linguagem deve ser usada.

## Validade dos testes de performance

Também a título de curiosidade, pode ser vista [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17408/101) que postei sobre o C#. Ali mostra bem que naquela linguagem o código das duas formas produzem o mesmo *bytecode* (código intermediário) e deve produzir o mesmo código nativo. Por isto não tem como haver diferença de performance. Então cada situação é diferente.

Em PHP poderia acontecer exatamente a mesma coisa, mas não acontece.

Note que apesar de alguns pseudo programadores acharem que é possível comparar performance de linguagens de programação ou mesmo de mecanismos diferentes de uma mesma linguagem, isto não é possível. Dá até para [brincar com o assunto](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/), mas não dá para fazer estudos conclusivos sérios. Alguns mais conscientes até dirão que você não pode comparar linguagens porque elas são abstratas e possuem versões diferentes. Então seria possível comparar implementações que é algo mais concreto. Nem isto é possível.

Mesmo comparar situações hipotéticas devem ser consideradas com uma pitada de sal. Dá para comparar algoritmos reais usados em situações reais. Então eu vou **comparar algoritmos** e não exatamente o operador condicional versus o comando condicional. Compararei um processamento mais amplo que usam estes mecanismos. Nem tem como comparar só eles. Compararei algo que faz muito mais que estas operações.

Também é bom perceber que executarei o teste em um ambiente que não é o ideal. Outros fatores podem influenciar o resultado rodando no ideone. Além disto o que funciona bem rodando em uma máquina pode rodar diferente em outra. Não acredito que isto vá ocorrer com este teste em PHP, mas lembre-se disto em qualquer *benchmark* que ver. Este é mais um motivo que nos impede de confiar nestes testes.

## O teste

Veja o [teste no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Q7lePX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kyoobodl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ConditionalOperatorPerformance.php).

Execute algumas vezes para ver que dá diferença.

```
$inicio = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $var = $i;
}
echo (microtime(true) - $inicio) * 1000 . "\n";

$inicio = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $var = $i == 500 ? 0 : $i;
}
echo (microtime(true) - $inicio) * 1000 . "\n";

$inicio = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    if ($i == 500) {
        $var =  0;
    } else {
        $var = $i;
    }
}
echo (microtime(true) - $inicio) * 1000 . "\n";
```

Note que o que gasta tempo mesmo são outras coisas. É o controle do laço com todas as operações necessárias nele - incremento, comparação, decisão e desvio - além do gasto em atribuir um valor à variável.

Eu não sei que otimizações o PHP faz e pode ser que este teste nem seja o ideal. Acredito que ele não faça nenhuma otimização relevante. Eu fiz alguns testes anteriores para tentar perceber se há alguma otimização que prejudique o teste de forma indevida, mas parece não haver. Posso estar enganado. Se alguém puder dar informações que ajudem melhorar o teste, ajudaria a todos. Mas eu sei que nenhum teste será perfeito. Em teoria podemos criar um teste perfeito mas é muito difícil reunir todas condições.

O primeiro laço só executa as repetições e faz uma atribuição normal para saber quanto tempo leva para fazer isto. O segundo obviamente usa o condicional e o terceiro dá para ver que usa o `if`.

Não é curioso que o `if` foi mais rápido? Note que dá para para perceber que o uso do `if` aumenta em cerca de 2 décimos de segundo o tempo total de processamento. Pode variar quando você mandar executar. E o ternário aumenta mais 2 décimos. Então podemos concluir, a grosso modo que o ternário leva o dobro do tempo que o `if`. Mas não é o tempo necessariamente gasto com o mecanismo em si, é uma medição do processamento desta parte do algoritmo.

## Relevância do teste

Mas tenha em mente que é assim na forma como foi usado. Em outra forma poderia dar outro resultado completamente diferente. Mesmo assim, percebeu como esta operação gasta pouco tempo comparado com todo o processamento? O laço e atribuição consomem 10 vezes mais tempo. Pelo menos é assim nesta versão do PHP, neste computador.

Eu cheguei fazer um teste executando mais que uma simples atribuição de variável, algo mais pesado, mas não muito pesado - algo que normalmente poderia ocorrer em situação real. A diferença de um algoritmo para outro que no teste demostrado já está na faixa dos 10%, caiu para menos de 1%.

Percebe como não costuma ser relevante? Em processamentos reais rodando em sistemas em produção, essa diferença costuma ser inferior.

A execução de cada uma dessas operações levou cerca de 20 à 40 microssegundos. É muito pouco. Claro que comparado com outras linguagens com código nativo que podem fazer o mesmo na casa dos nanossegundos, isto é trágico. Mas é bom o suficiente para o PHP.

## Conclusão

Há um ganho claro do comando condicional nesta situação. Mas não garanto que ocorra em todas. É provável, mas não garantido. O ganho é pequeno, especialmente se considerar ele em um processamento maior, que é o caso que praticamente qualquer código real. O ganho é tão pequeno que se ele fizer diferença no que seu software precisa, PHP é a linguagem errada.

Então a escolha deve recair em qual é mais legível, qual passa melhor a intenção. Lembrando que código curto costuma ser mais legível, até que ele fique muito amontoado, aí o tamanho começa jogar contra. Código curto não deve ser o objetivo, a clareza e expressividade, sim. Performance vem bem depois.

Só reforçando que este teste não pode ser considerado válido nem mesmo entre versões diferentes do PHP, muito menos para outras linguagens.

Comment: Claro que é no caso de performance.

Comment: De qualquer modo, eu participei de um estudo muito sério comparando um algoritmo de análise de imagens entre linguagens e foi possível determinar qual linguagem tinha a performance necessária para aquela função. Depois do estudo tivemos que introduzir mais uma linguagem no projeto para cuidar daquele recurso em particular, por requisito de performance. Nenhum dos envolvidos era pseudo-programador.

Comment: `para aquela função` era o segredo. E mesmo assim se pegar o mesmo estudo e aplicar anos depois com as mesmas linguagens mas com suas versões mais modernas em computadores mais modernos, o resultado não será o mesmo. É possível até que não invalide o estudo mas diminui sua relevância. Eu não tenho dados sobre isto para falar. Eu só posso falar sobre o que eu conheço. Não tem espaço aqui para entrar em detalhes sobre o assunto. Se você conhece bem o assunto sabe do que estou falando. Se não conhece vamos ficar debatendo improdutivamente.

Comment: Ok, com o seu comentário eu entendi o seu ponto que eu não tinha entendido antes só com a leitura da resposta.

Comment: Boa noite, realmente não entendi isto: *PHP é uma linguagem onde a performance não é importante.* Você se refere aos operadores ou você quer dizer outra coisa? A frase soa estranho, poderia explicar?

Comment: Não, me refiro a tudo, ninguém escolhe esta linguagem porque ela é rápida. Você poderia explicar porque soa estranho? Quem sabe aí eu poderia esclarecer.

Comment: Por que você não usou o `@usuario` eu não havia visto a sua mensagem, ok, para mim ao menos soa como que em "PHP a performance não importa", isto soa como se eu fizesse qualquer coisa no PHP e ele não tivesse problema de performance, ou que em PHP as coisa podem ser lenta. Não to querendo dizer que é isto o que você quis dizer, mas com certeza soa como outra coisa para a maioria que ler, claro que fica ao seu critério acreditar no que digo ou não. Geralmente quando escrevemos do nosso entendimento, dificilmente levamos em consideração o entendimento que soa para os outros, isto é humano.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pode ser, depois eu dou uma revisada, embora a ideia é +/- esta mesmo. Fora cometer grandes absurdos, tornar quadrático algo que pode ser linear, ou coisas do tipo, não adianta querer otimizar muito as coisas em PHP, dificilmente terá um efeito relevante. Então colocarei algo para deixar claro que o PHP é lento mesmo.

Comment: Agora entendi, apesar de discordar, quero dizer: talvez em questões de APIs servidores, etc, podemos dizer que realmente não tem o que melhorar, mas em questão de como é programado pelo usuário, acredito que isto se torne uma informação errada, mas é apenas a minha opinião. Grato e um bom feriado pra ti.

Answer (score 7):

Ambos são iguais, nenhum é melhor que o outro, se há alguma diferença, ela é *insignificante*, a unica vantagem de uma operação ternária é a legibilidade e um código mais *limpo*.

Usar um ou outro dependerá do contexto, numa situação que seja necessário executar várias instruções, o `if {..} else {..}` é *preferível*, quando for para executar uma única instrução, por exemplo, atribuir um valor a uma variável, é *possível* usar o ternário.

Situação onde o `if/else` é apropriado:

```
if ($foo){
  instrucao1()
  instrucao2()
  instrucaoN()
} else {
  outraInstrucao1()
  outraInstrucao2()
  outraInstrucaoN()
}
```

Situação onde o operador ternário é apropriado:

```
$x = $foo ? "Foo" : "John Doe";
```

A partir do [PHP 5.3](http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php) é possível usar o *atalho ternário* `?:`:

> Desde o PHP 5.3, é possível deixar de fora a parte do meio do operador ternário. A Expressão `Expr1 :? Expr3` devolve `Expr1` se `Expr1` é avaliada como *True*, ou `Expr3` caso contrário.

Exemplo:

```
$foo = "Foo";
$x = $foo ?: "John Doe";
```

Answer (score 7):

## Desambiguação

O operador ternário como lhe chamas é um operador condicional, comummente conhecido por operador ternário por fazer parte do grupo de operadores ternários (3 operandos).

Ambos fazem uso de uma condição avaliando a mesma para um resultado booleano que lhes vai permitir prosseguir com a lógica.

## Quem é mais rápido

No caso do operador condicional `?:`, o mesmo não passa de uma expressão que opera na base de um movimento condicional <sup>*cmov*</sup>.

O operador condicional `if~else` opera na base de uma árvore <sup>*branches*</sup>.

Esta diferença de operação, proveniente de c/c++, as linguagens de implementação do PHP, à uns anos atrás poderiam fazer alguma diferença, onde o operador condicional `?:` ficava à frente em termos de performance.

Nos dias de hoje, a diferença é impercetível e a comparação entre os dois fútil.

## E então, qual utilizar?

`?:` é mais prático em:

- Simples verificações:

  ```
  $sair = ($resposta=="sim");
  ```
- Verificações *inline*:

  ```
  echo "Olá" . (isLogged() ? $user->name : "Convidado");
  ```
- Inicializar variáveis:

  ```
  $bubu = ("chocolate"=="bom") ? 'sem fome' : 'com fome';
  ```

`if~else` é mais prático em:

- Verificações complexas:

  ```
  if (isLogged() && accessRights()!=4 && "bubu"=="com fome") {
     $mensagem = "Vamos lá" . groupName();
  }
  else {
      $mensagem = "Ninguém vai a lado nenhum!";
  }
  ```
- Verificações multiplas:

  ```
  if ($bubu=="cheio") {
      $mensagem = "Parar de comer";
  }
  else if ($bubu=="assim assim") {
      $mensagem = "Comer mais um pouco!";
  }
  else {
      $mensagem = "Enfardar até cair pró lado!";
  }
  ```

Em suma a vantagem está mais do lado do programador e na facilidade de tornar o código legível bem como de o manter.