# Como organizar o código sem perder desempenho?

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, otimização

Usar funções no lugar de colocar o código diretamente influencia muito no desempenho de um programa ? Por exemplo:

```
void minhafuncao(){
  printf("Funcao");
}
main(){
  minhafuncao();
}
```

no lugar de

```
main(){
  printf("Funcao");
}
```

Eu sei que macros tem uma performance maior do que funções, mas até o momento eu só vi macros com operações aritméticas. Tem como colocar blocos de código com vários comandos em uma macro ? Ou, se não, alguma outra forma de fazer que tenha um melhor desempenho ?

Comment: Ter o código numa função separada ou directamente dentro doutra função não influencia o desempenho de forma observável.

Comment: Na verdade, pmg, depende do caso. Funções que somente fazem, por exemplo, uma ou duas operações aritméticas e que são chamadas em loop aos montes podem consumir um percentual maior e notável de tempo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Usar funções no lugar de colocar o código diretamente influencia muito no desempenho de um programa ?

Não! Chamadas de função, ainda mais em C, são bastante rápidas. Tem muitas outras coisas que vão deixar o seu programa bem mais lento do que uma chamada de função:

[image: latências para diversas operações]

Como você pode ver nessa imagem, um único acesso ao disco rígido gasta um tempo equivalente a milhões de chamadas de função. Um acesso a um computador remoto nem se fala então.

E mesmo se as chamadas de função fossem lentas, (o que elas não são) o benefício que elas oferecem em termos de abstração e organização do código é muito grande e não valeria a pena abrir mão disso em nome de "performance". Quando se trata de otimizar um programa, o que faz diferença é a performance dos "gargalos": se você tem um loop interno consumindo 90% do seu tempo de execução, dobrar a velocidade dele vai ter um efeito significativo. Por outro lado, se um trecho do seu código só executa umas centenas de vezes, mesmo se você torná-lo instantâneo você não vai economizar mais do que alguns milissegundos. Por isso, **sempre meça a performance do seu programa antes de começar a otimizá-lo**! É difícil prever de antemão quais partes do seu programa são os verdadeiros gargalos e qualquer otimização fora do gargalo é uma perda de tempo que só serve para deixar seu código mais complicados. Sem contar que algumas otimizações podem acabar deixando seu programa mais lento do que antes. A única forma de se proteger disso é sempre medir antes e depois de qualquer otimização que você fizer.

> sei que macros tem uma performance maior do que funções

Nem sempre! Macros são uma forma manual de [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) e o uso excessivo dessa técnica aumenta bastante o tamanho do executável. Além de desperdiçar memória, isso pode aumentar a taxa de "cache miss", o que é bastante prejudicial à performance (um acesso à memória RAM exige centenas de ciclos).

Além disso, o verdadeiro ganho de performance do inlining são vem do custo da chamada de função mas sim das oportunidades que o otimizador passa a ter para especializar o código da subrotina para o local da chamada (alocação melhor de registradores, remoção de código morto, etc). Isso nem sempre acaba valendo a pena e por isso recomendo confiar no seu compilador ao invés de sair fazendo inlining na mão.

Comment: Pior, que as vezes esses "gargalos" no código as vezes se tornam necessários quando o trecho sem tal gargalo se mostra uma tarefa demasiadamente complicada. Ex: As vezes se torna melhor para o entendimento percorrer um array todo - com for e um if interno - do que tentar achar expressões complicadíssimas no for e satisfazer as mesmas condições sem percorrer todo array.

Comment: É verdade, Rafael, e é sempre importante levar em conta o custo de deixar o programa mais complicado. Mas pior ainda é fazer artimanhas de otimização em algo que nem é um gargalo :)

Answer (score 7):

À princípio influencia a performance. Mas pode não influenciar por uma série de fatores.

Uma chamada à uma função, além das instruções de desvio e retorno do fluxo do programa para um outro endereço, pode existir a cópia de dos parâmetros, seja de memória para memória, seja através de registradores. Então tem custo, claro.

Se a função for simples e dependendo das opções usadas para compilar o programa a função será otimizada através de da chamada [*inline expansion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion). Ou seja, se for vantajoso, o compilador elimina a chamada da função e coloca o código dela no local onde era feita a chamada. Note que o compilador sabe que há casos que usar esta técnica produzirá resultado contrário.

Isso faz o mesmo que a macro faria mas de forma muito melhor. No início os compiladores não eram capazes de fazer isto e as macros traziam esta vantagem, apesar das desvantagens que este recurso possui. Hoje não existe mais grandes motivos para o uso da macro, apenas situações muito específicas exigem seu uso em código C e menos ainda em código C++ que tem ainda mais recursos melhores.

É possível fazer macros mais complexas que simples operações aritméticas mas não é recomendado o seu uso nos dias de hoje. Mas como já disse antes macros não entendem o contexto onde estão sendo executadas, isto pode causar problemas se cuidados não forem tomados na sua criação e/ou uso.

Exemplo:

```
#define exemplo() \
  do { \
    faz alguma coisa aqui \
  } while (0)
```

Hoje não tem mais razão para fazer isso. Hoje até mesmo em C, na maior parte do tempo o programador deve se preocupar com a legibilidade do código e não com a performance. O compilador fará o código ser o mais rápido possível na imensa maioria das situações que o código for bem escrito. Não é necessário ficar procurando as melhores formas de escrever pensando primariamente na performance. Quando a performance não for suficiente, aí deve-se pensar no que fazer para melhorar aquele trecho. raramente a macro será a solução para este caso.

Em quase 100% dos casos o compilador saberá se uma função deve ser "linearizada" para obter melhor desempenho. Se ele não fizer isto é porque ele entende que não haverá ganho e ele acerta mais que os programadores costumam fazer.

Me parece que alguns compiladores podem forçar fazer o *inline*, através de *flag* específica, mesmo quando não é recomendado. Quase sempre quando o programador quer ser mais esperto que o compilador, ele erra.

O seu exemplo é certo que será "linearizada", a não ser que o compilador seja instruído a não fazer. Mas uma pequena mudança que ainda deixará a função curta provavelmente impedirá que isto aconteça:

```
void minhafuncao(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) printf("Funcao");
}
```

Provavelmente o tempo gasto dentro da função é grande o suficiente para o compilador entender que não haverá ganho. Mas outros fatores podem ser levados em consideração para fazer a avaliação.

Não vou entrar em detalhes do que é feito ou não porque não conheço profundamente e depende de implementação, ou seja, pode mudar em cada versão ou marca do compilador.

Um teste pode ser aplicado para ver se há diferença ou não:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int minhafuncao(){
    int x = 0;
    x++;
    return x;
}

int main () {
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;
    int x;
    begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000000; i++);
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf ("Tempo gasto %.2lf segundos.\n", time_spent);
    begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000000; i++) minhafuncao();
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf ("Tempo gasto %.2lf segundos.\n", time_spent);
    begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000000; i++) x++;
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf ("Tempo gasto %.2lf segundos.\n", time_spent);
    x++;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/NrSfcQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ulivgfpa-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Performance.c).

O ideone ou outro site do tipo não é o melhor ambiente para fazer o teste mas dá para ter uma ideia. Recomendo fazer o seu teste. O resultado pode ser diferente em condições diferentes.

Outro teste sem retornar um valor. Note como muda. Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/XWIdIY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fmeexagl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Performance2.c).

Comment: gcc -Wall -ansi -O velocidade.c -o velocidade -> Na execução: 
Tempo gasto 0.10 segundos.
Tempo gasto 0.10 segundos.
Tempo gasto 0.10 segundos.  Sem a flag -O (0.7, 0.83, 0.7)

Comment: Exatamente, é o que eu falei, tudo vai depender de como compila.

Comment: No código por que minhafunção retorna um valor? Sem o retorno o tempo sem -O também é parecido.

Comment: Pra mostrar que qualquer coisa pode fazer diferença. Que não dá para falar de velocidade de coisas hipotéticas. Um pequeno detalhe muda tudo. Certamente ele quer saber que deve usar qualquer função ou não. E isto **depende**, mesmo uma simples mudança **pode** produzir um resultado diferente. E falo mais sobre isto aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56838/101 é bobagem generalizar comparação de performance, ela só pode ser feito de forma muito específica, em casos reais.

Comment: Muito bom código, realmente sempre ouvi falar de performance, e isso fica sucinto nesse pequeno código. Vou testar umas flags, outros compiladores, alguns statics, inlines etc. Mutio bom exemplo!

Comment: Nem acho que ele seja muito bom, só mostra como é fácil ver que depende até em coisas simples. Em complexas, o depende fica enorme. Tem outras otimizações que podem ocorrer aí. Pode ter até mesmo [*dead code elimination*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination). O que pode justificar tempos iguais. Não é o caso mas pode ser que uma otimização propicie outra, como um [*loop unrolling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) ou [*constant folding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding), só para citar algumas otimizações óbvias.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22718/discussion-between-rafael-bluhm-and-bigown).

Comment: Ambas as respostas foram bastante esclarecedoras.