# Como fazer uma busca pra saber se uma string está dentro de um vetor no C#

Tags: c#, .net, array

Eu estou fazendo um pequeno programa que faz busca dentro de um vetor. O problema que eu to tendo é que se ele encontra o nome ele dá uma mensagem dizendo que foi encontrado mas logo em seguida dá outra mensagem dizendo que não foi encontrado, o código que eu to criando é esse:

```
string[] nomes = { "misael", "camila", "fernando" };

for (int i = 0; i < nomes.Length; i++) {
    if (txtbusca.Text == nomes[i])
    {
        MessageBox.Show("nome encontrado");
    }    
}

for (int i = 0; i < nomes.Length; i++) {
    if (txtbusca.Text != nomes[i])
    {
        MessageBox.Show("nome não encontrado");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Se alguma das repostas te ajudou marque como correta para que futuros visitantes tenham uma referência.

Comment: E sou nova aqui, não sei como faz isso

Comment: É só clicar no símbolo de **checked** `✔`
http://imgur.com/a/sJi2a

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O problema é que no segundo *for* a mensagem é apresentada mal encontre um nome diferente.

Não necessita de percorrer o array duas vezes.
Caso ele seja percorrido até ao fim sem encontrar, é porque o nome não está no array.

```
string[] nomes = { "misael", "camila", "fernando" };  

string message = "nome não encontrado";
for (int i = 0; i < nomes.Length; i++) {
    if (txtbusca.Text == nomes[i])
    {
        message = "nome encontrado";
        break; //Foi encontrado, não necessita de procurar mais
    }    
}
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

É claro que existem formas mais simples de fazer isso. No entanto, já que está aprendendo, é importante saber o que está errado no seu código e saber resolve-lo na forma "tradicional", antes de usar recursos mais "avançados" da linguagem.

Comment: muito obrigada pela ajuda

Answer (score 12):

Se puder usar LINQ ([`Contains()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_)) pode resolver já no `if` que decide se encontrou ou não.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string[] nomes = { "misael", "camila", "fernando" };
        var txtBusca = "camila";
        if (nomes.Contains(txtBusca)) {
            WriteLine("Nome encontrado");
        } else {
            WriteLine("Nome não encontrado");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5uXxXH). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A4wwfi).  Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/ContainInArray.cs).

Se quiser dá para simplificar ainda mais e [até eliminar o `if`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17398/101), então 5 linhas (ou 7 dependendo do estilo) podem virar apenas uma.

Obviamente troquei a variável e o método de escrita em tela para poder testar sem dependência da sua aplicação, o que alias me lembra que tela e regra de negócio deveriam estar separados. Se for só um exercício, tudo bem, mas tenha isto em mente.

No seu código ficaria assim:

```
string[] nomes = { "misael", "camila", "fernando" };
MessageBox.Show(nomes.Contains(txtBusca.Text) ? "Nome encontrado" : "Nome não encontrado");
```

Answer (score 6):

Usa o `Contains`:

```
string[] nomes = { "misael", "camila", "fernando" };

if(nomes.contains(txtbusca.Text))
    MessageBox.Show("nome encontrado");
else
    MessageBox.Show("nome não encontrado");
```

Comment: muito obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: Na verdade isto só funciona se estiver usando LINQ. E o método é `Contains()`. E falta fechar um parentese, mas esses dois erros são só digitação. E a falta de chaves não causará problemas aí, mas é um estilo que ajuda causar problemas de manutenção.

Comment: @bigown, se não estou em erro, o método Contains() é para procurar dentro de uma string, enquanto o método contains() é para procurar dentro de um array. Pelo que percebi da pergunta ele queria procurar se um array continha uma string e não se uma string continha uma sequência de caracteres.

Comment: Não, não existe `contains()`, nenhum método do .NET é minúsculo. Ele procura em qualquer objeto enumerável. O tipo `string` tem um `Contains()` especializado, mas se não tivesse, funcionaria com LINQ. Sem LINQ só se o tipo tiver e poucos têm, `List` é um dos que tem também. Na minha resposta eu até mostrei que funciona da forma esperada, a sua nem compila, pode testar.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar Linq para encontrar também

```
string[] nomes = { "misael", "camila", "fernando" };

if (nomes.Count(x => x == txtbusca.Text) > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("nome encontrado");
else
    MessageBox.Show("nome não encontrado");
```

No `Count(x => x == txtbusca.Text)` estou atribuindo uma variável `x` que terá o valor de cada item do array depois eu comparo o valor de `x` com o do seu`TextBox`, no final deste processo você terá a quantidade de nomes que foram encontrado.

Depois eu verifico se o sistema encontrou ao meno um nome com o `> 0`

Comment: Dica: não precisa fazer `Where` e depois `Count`. O Count também recebe um predicado.

Comment: Complementando: Usar `Any(x => x == txtbusca.Text)` parece uma opção melhor ainda.