# Como fazer um if else em um select ao criar um objeto?

Tags: linq, expressões-lambda

Não sei se o título ficou bom, mas a pergunta é o seguinte:

```
listaAgendaDetalhe = (from a in listaAgenda
                      join p in listaProfissional
                      on a.idProfissional equals p.id
                      select new agendaDetalhe()
                      {
                      ativo = p.ativo,
                      dataIni = a.dataIni,
                      especialidade = a.especialidade,
                      if (a.frequencia = 0)
                      frequencia = 'DIARIO'
                      else if (a.frequencia = 1)
                      frequencia = 'SEMANAL'
                      else if (a.frequencia = 2)
                      frequencia = 'QUINZENAL'
                      }).ToList();
```

A dúvida é no campo `frequencia`, quero fazer uma verificação antes de atribuir um valor pra ele, mas do jeito que eu fiz, não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use assim:**

```
listaAgendaDetalhe = (from a in listaAgenda
                      join p in listaProfissional
                      on a.idProfissional equals p.id
                      select new agendaDetalhe()
                      {
                          ativo = p.ativo,
                          dataIni = a.dataIni,
                          especialidade = a.especialidade,
                          frequencia = a.frequencia == 0 ? "DIARIO" : a.frequencia == 1 ? "SEMANAL" : "QUINZENAL",
                      }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Nesse caso você pode utilizar um [if ternario](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17408/26133) para isso, ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
listaAgendaDetalhe = (from a in listaAgenda
                      join p in listaProfissional
                      on a.idProfissional equals p.id
                      select new agendaDetalhe()
                      {
                      ativo = p.ativo,
                      dataIni = a.dataIni,
                      especialidade = a.especialidade,
                      a.frequencia == 0 ? "DIARIO" : a.frequencia == 1 ? "SEMANAL" : a.frequencia == 2 ? "QUINZENAL" : null
                      }).ToList();
```