# 2 casa decimais utilizando o double

Tags: java, android

Estou aprender a programar, estou a fazer uma aplicação com 3 edittext(onde insiro os números que quero calcular) e uma textview para apresentar o resultado. Gostaria de saber como faço para calcular 2 números com opção de poder preencher o terceiro edittext. E gostaria de saber como posso converter o meu resultado em 2 casas decimais.

Deixo aqui o código:

```
public void somar (View v){

        EditText odd1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        String stringodd1 = odd1.getText().toString();

        EditText odd2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        String stringodd2 = odd2.getText().toString();

        EditText odd3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
        String stringodd3 = odd3.getText().toString();

        EditText montante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
        String stringmontante = montante.getText().toString();


        if (stringodd1.trim().isEmpty() || stringodd2.trim().isEmpty() || stringodd3.trim().isEmpty())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campos em branco",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {

            double valorodd1 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd1);
            double valorodd2 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd2);
            double valorodd3 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd2);
            double valormontante = Double.parseDouble(stringmontante);


            double resu = valorodd1 * valorodd2 * valorodd3 * valormontante;



            TextView resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        resultado.setText (resu + "€" );




    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá fiz umas modificações no seu código. O usuário pode entrar com um numero ou mais que será efetuado o calculo, modifiquei sua condição para não fazer operação quando as 3 entradas são nulas( *mas se retirar o `if` o código também funciona* ). Assim o usuário pode digitar em qualquer uma das `edittext` que funcionará( *fiz assim pois não entendi bem como queria*). Inseri a mascara para formatar a saída de forma a ter somente 2 casas decimais.

Bom pode não ser exatamente o que você esteja querendo mas acho que a partir dessas modificações você consegue fazer o que está querendo

[o que é um operador ternário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17398/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-if-e-operador-tern%C3%A1rio)

```
public void somar (View v){

    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    EditText odd1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    String stringodd1 = odd1.getText().toString();

    EditText odd2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    String stringodd2 = odd2.getText().toString();

    EditText odd3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    String stringodd3 = odd3.getText().toString();

    EditText montante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
    String stringmontante = montante.getText().toString();

    double valorodd1,valorodd2,valorodd3;

    //verificando se valores sao nulos
    stringodd1.trim().isEmpty() ? valorodd1 = 1 : valorodd1 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd1);
    stringodd2.trim().isEmpty() ? valorodd2 = 1 : valorodd2 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd2);
    stringodd3.trim().isEmpty() ? valorodd3 = 1 : valorodd3 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd2);
    // verificando se todos os valores são nulos obs: esse controle pode ser retirado que a logica também funcionará 
    if (stringodd1.trim().isEmpty() && stringodd2.trim().isEmpty() && stringodd3.trim().isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campos em branco",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        double valormontante = Double.parseDouble(stringmontante);


        double resu = valorodd1 * valorodd2 * valorodd3 * valormontante;


        TextView resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        resultado.setText (formatter.format(resu) + "€" );



    }
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde, tentei seguir a sua edição, esta-me a dar erro no "'?" em: stringodd1.trim().isEmpty() ? valorodd1 = 1 : valorodd1 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd1);
    stringodd2.trim().isEmpty() ? valorodd2 = 1 : valorodd2 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd2);
    stringodd3.trim().isEmpty() ? valorodd3 = 1 : valorodd3 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd2); que posso fazer? Obrigado

Comment: if(stringodd1.trim().isEmpty()){valorodd1 = 1;  } else{valorodd1 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd1);}

para cada operador ternário

Comment: Consegui amigo. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar um `NumberFormat` junto com `DecimalFormat`.

Quanto à validação, você apenas quer validar dois valores, mas na condição tinha os três valores a serem validados. Sendo assim removi a validação do terceiro número:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
...
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

if (stringodd1.trim().isEmpty() || stringodd2.trim().isEmpty())
...
resultado.setText(formatter.format(resu) + "€");
```

Comment: Está feito :). Em relação ao calculo das edittext, imaginamos por exemplo 5 caixas onde inserimos 5 números e multiplicamos esses 5 número e obtemos o resultado, a minha ideia é ter a opção de multiplicar por exemplo apenas 2 caixas ou mesmo 3 caixas.. Obrigado