# Qual seria o nome dessa "técnica"?

Tags: c, operadores, operador-lógico

```
int valorNo = (p->left == NULL && p->right == NULL) ? p->key : 0;
```

Vi isso em uma resposta aqui no stack e não faço a mínima ideia de como isso funciona, muito menos de como "ler" isso.

Comment: Isso o que? Tem muitas coisas aí.

Comment: @Matheus, pelo que entendi, seia o operador ternário: Expressão_de_teste 
  ? Expressão_executada_se_verdadeiro 
  : Expressão_executada_se_falso;   Sendo bem explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17398/6789).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é um Operador Ternário. Basicamente, é a mesma coisa que fazer:

```
if (p->left == NULL && p->right == NULL)
{
    int valorNo = p->key;
}
else
{
    int valorNo = 0;
}
```

Sendo estruturado da seguinte forma:

```
(CONDIÇÃO) ? OPERAÇÃO VERDADEIRA : OPERAÇÃO FALSA;
```

É uma maneira simplificada de criar condições no código.