# Lógica Jquery ' ? ' e ' : '

Tags: jquery

Olá, sou iniciante no jquery, e estava vendo a documentação do Jquery Ui, Draggable e Droppable. Eu estou estudando a demonstração do site, mas não entendo essa parte:

```
var $list = $( "ul", $trash ).length ?
  $( "ul", $trash ) :
  $( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" ).appendTo( $trash );
```

Não entendo a parte do `?` depois do `.length` e o `:` depois do `$( "ul", $trash )`. 
Essa é a função completa:

```
function deleteImage( $item ) {

  $item.fadeOut(function() {
    var $list = $( "ul", $trash ).length ?
      $( "ul", $trash ) :
      $( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" ).appendTo( $trash );

    $item.find( "a.ui-icon-trash" ).remove();
    $item.append( recycle_icon ).appendTo( $list ).fadeIn(function() {
      $item
        .animate({ width: "48px" })
        .find( "img" )
          .animate({ height: "36px" });
    });
  });
}
```

E essa é a evento que chama a função:

```
var $gallery = $( "#gallery" ),
      $trash = $( "#trash" );

$trash.droppable({
  accept: "#gallery > li",  
  classes: {    
    "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"
  },
  drop: function( event, ui ) { 
    deleteImage( ui.draggable );
  }
});
```

Comment: Se chama "operador ternário". Você encontra mais material aqui no site. Por exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17398/64969

Comment: É uma boa pergunta, mas já temos resposta dela no site.

Comment: Sugiro deixar a pergunta que citei como duplicada, visto que aborda o assunto diretamente em JS. Para novos usuários, acredito que isso facilitará. Se alguém fechar e adicionar todas como relacionadas, melhor.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Concordo totalmente.